# JNDI with spring mvc3 integration

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, jdbc, jndi

I am using Spring MVC 3 and MySQL server. I am trying to use JNDI for the JDBC connectivity, but it returns NULL DataSource. Here is the piece of code which throws null pointer exception.

`server.xml` file that contain:

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

`context.xml` file content

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/Test" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="root" password="123456" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
```

`web.xml` file cantain:

```
     <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/Test</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

`despatcher-servlet.xml` file:

```
    <bean name="myDataSourceInJndi" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/Test</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="dbConfiguration" class="com.biztree.springtest.database.DataBaseConfiguration" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSourceInJndi" />
    </bean>
```

`DataBaseConfiguration.java`

```
package com.biztree.springtest.database;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class DataBaseConfiguration {

    DataSource dataSource;

    public DataBaseConfiguration() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

and hear is the code to connect

```
          /*    this code work throw NullPointerException */
        try {

            DataBaseConfiguration baseConfiguration = new DataBaseConfiguration();
            DataSource ds = baseConfiguration.getDataSource();
            System.out.println("ds Object : " + ds);
            connection = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but it `ds` is null.

If I use following code than it working properly

```
          /*    this code work fine */
        try {
            Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)  envCtx.lookup("jdbc/Test");

            System.out.println("ds Object : " + ds);
            connection = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Where is the `<Resource>` element for your datasource? See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: <Resource> element is in <GlobalNamingResources> in server.xml

Comment: sorry axtavt , i forgot to write <resource> element in question my resource in context.xml

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn on debug logging for spring, and/or debug spring to see what it's actually looking up, and compare that with what your direct JNDI code is doing.

something like this could be throwing you off as well:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiLocatorSupport.html#setResourceRef(boolean)

( you set this property on the JndiObjectFactoryBean and it will automatically add the comp/env part... check for what the default value is and make sure it's set correctly)

anyway you will be able to confirm once you debug spring to see what it's doing.